# Vertical-Responsive CSS image

Tags: css, responsive, responsive-images

I know that we can create a responsive horizontal image easily, like that.

```
.img-horiz-resp {
  max-width:100%;
  height:auto;
}
```

But, in my case I need :

- a header on top
- a content (for now it can be a simple image)
- a footer

Then, when resizing the browser vertically, I wish that the 'content' adapt its size.

I have try here : https://codepen.io/cdemez/pen/qBbKVYp

But without success.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question can you give me some explanation

Comment: Could this be what you're looking for? [https://codepen.io/symphonic15/pen/rNxKpBG](https://codepen.io/symphonic15/pen/rNxKpBG)

Answer (score 0):

By using VH for the height you can get you image responsive (there are other ways too, but this is simple).
VH is used for how much of the available height that should be used, like percent (%). 100VH is the whole screen from top to bottom, regardless of your screen size.
Now I put the image in the css-file (and used it ONLY as background, not background-image), but if you want to use it in your html-file, remember to set your with to 100%.
https://jsfiddle.net/battleaxe/u07cfbog/#&togetherjs=lbxrukCzHi

HTML:

```css
 * {
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    body {
      height: 100%;
      min-height: 100%;
      font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;

      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      align-items: center;
    }
    header {
      height: 6vh;
      width: 100%;
      background-color: #2e4b49;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
    }
    ul {
      width: 60%;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: space-between;
      list-style: none;
      color: #fff;
      text-transform: uppercase;
    }
    .content {
      height: 84vh;
      width: 100%;
      background: url("https://cdn.socloze.com/cdn/e_663aa122-718e-a8d3-301d-39f64b8523b0/ebdc5bef01506acc759b39f64b9cc917.jpg")
        no-repeat center center;
      background-size: contain;
      /* You can use background-size: cover; if you want the image to cover your whole free space. */
    }
    footer {
      height: 10vh;
      width: 100%;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      background-color: #2e4b49;
      color: #fff;
    }
```

```html
   




    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
        <title>Document</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <header>
          <ul>
            <li>This</li>
            <li>Is</li>
            <li>a</li>
            <li>Header</li>
          </ul>
        </header>
        <div class="content"></div>
        <footer>
          <p>This is a footer</p>
        </footer>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Things you can look up are VH and VW, how the work and how they can be used. Also, try different background-sizes (cover, contain, and so on).

Good Luck!